# NGRX 4: How to combine data from multiple sources

Tags: firebase, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

Question on how to combine reducers / data in app state:

Example of Data (Firebase):

```
{
    "artists" : {
        "168dgYui7ExaU612eooDF1" : {
            "name" : "Brand New",
            "id" : "168dgYui7ExaU612eooDF1",
        }
    },
    "genres" : {
        "popPunk" : {
            "name" : "pop punk"
        },
        "screamo" : {
            "name" : "screamo"
        }
    },
    "genresPerArtist" : {
        "168dgYui7ExaU612eooDF1" : {
            "popPunk" : true,
            "screamo" : true
        }
    }
}
```

App State:

```
export type State = { app: AppState };
    export type AppState = { genres: IGenre[], artistGenres: IGenre[], artists: any[], currentArtist: any };
    export const initialState: State = {
        app: {
            artists: [],
            currentArtist: null,
            genres: [],
            artistGenres: []
        }
    }
```

Reducer:

```
export function appReducer(state: AppState, action: GenreActions.Actions): AppState {
    // TODO: add reducers for Fetch Artist and Fetch Artists
    switch (action.type) {
        case GenreActions.FETCH_GENRES: {
            return { ...state };
        }
        case GenreActions.FETCH_GENRES_SUCCESS: {
            return { ...state, genres: action.payload };
        }
        case GenreActions.FETCH_ARTIST_GENRES: {
            return { ...state };
        }
        case GenreActions.FETCH_ARTIST_GENRES_SUCCESS: {
            return { ...state, artistGenres: action.payload };
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Effects:

```
@Effect()
FetchGenres$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(appActions.FETCH_GENRES)
    .switchMap(() => {
        return this.firebaseProvider.genres
            .map(payload => new appActions.FetchGenresSuccess(payload))
            .catch(() => of(new appActions.FetchGenresSuccess([])));
    });


// TODO: See if I should be using store's genres here, or if that should be combined elsewhere
@Effect()
FetchArtistGenres$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(appActions.FETCH_ARTIST_GENRES)
    .map((action: appActions.FetchArtistGenres) => { return action.payload })
    .switchMap((artistId: string) => {

        return this.firebaseProvider.genresByArtist(artistId)
            .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(state => state.app.genres))
            .map((results) => {
                let artistGenres = results[0];
                let genres = results[1];
                return genres.filter(genre => {
                    let result = artistGenres.findIndex(g => g.$key === genre.$key);
                    return (result ? true : false);
                });
            })
            .map(payload => new appActions.FetchArtistGenresSuccess(payload));
    });
```

Firebase Provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseProvider {
    genres: FirebaseListObservable<IGenre[]>;

    constructor(
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {
        this.genres = this.db.list('/genres');
    }

    genresByArtist(artistId: string): Observable<IDictionary[]> {
        return this.db.list(`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`);
    }
}
```

Artist Page:

My question is how are you supposed to combine different slices of the data in NGRX4?

Example: I have an Artist Detail page. In that page, I want to display the Artist info, along with the Artist's genres. Elsewhere, I might have a Artist List page where I display multiple artists and their genres. Where do I fetch and merge all of that relevant information in my app? In the reducer? In the effect (how FetchArtistGenres$ is currently doing it)?

Other concerns: I don't think I want to have the entire "genresPerArtist" or "artists" node in my app state, because it will eventually become very large and I'm not sure that would be performant (if I'm wrong here, and that's the way to go, let me know). Instead, I'd fetch the specific Artists genre node when I need it (`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`)

Comment: Create an action that dispatches both api calls to get what you need using `forkJoin`. Subscribing to it will return an array of results. Then, on the reducer update your state with new data. You can consider also adding a new state variable to be a `Map<Artist, Array<Genre>>` and viceversa.

Comment: @AndreaM16, thanks. I'll give that a try. forkJoin def seems useful, I think I misunderstood that one before. 
The only potential issue that I see is that in some cases, I need just Artist, other cases, I need just Genres, so I'd be duplicating those calls and data in my client state to get that separate data (one action for Genres, one action for Artist(s), one action for combined Artist/Genre.

Comment: I would have the following fields in my reducer: `{ artists : Artist[], genres: Genre: [], currentArstist: Artist, currentGenre: Genre, currentArtistsByGenre: Map<Genre, Artist[]>, currentGenresByArtist: Map<Artist, Genre[]> }.` In this way you should have artist/genre details if you need them and access each map in O(1) pretty easily.

Comment: Still working on the code, but I think `selectors` are what I was looking for: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md